# axios api call not working for vue router route path laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

This is my vue route list.

```
Vue.use(VueRouter)
let routes = [
    { path: '/dashboard', 
    component: require('./components/admin/DashboardComponent.vue').default,
    meta: {
      middleware: auth,
      } 
    },
    { path: '/users', component: require('./components/admin/UsersComponent.vue').default ,
    meta: {
      middleware: auth,
      } 
    },
    { path: '/content/hello', name:"editcontent", component: 
      require('./components/admin/EditContent.vue').default ,
        meta: {
          middleware: auth,
          } 
        }]
```

When I set route path convention like

```
path: /content/hello
```

, then component are working fine but when i call api by axios then it's not working. All time it returns an html file.

If i do not use extra ‍`/content/etc` and only use `/content` in path then it's working.

Comment: your axios call is supposed to call a route from you `laravel` `api` route list. Vue router is meant just for your front end navigation

Comment: Thank you response. Yes i know , same api are working other  vue router except ```path: /content/hello``` this type vue router.